# Is there a way to reuse variables during executemany?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pandas

I'm working on some ETL scripts and I have run into a problem where I'm using a MERGE statement. I am using `executemany` to run a SQL script that looks like this:

```
MERGE myTable as target
USING (
  SELECT myID from myTable
  WHERE myID = ?
) AS source (myID) ON (target.myID = source.myID)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (myID, myName, myProperty, myOtherProperty)
VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET myName=?, myProperty=?, etc...;
```

The issue here is that I need the `myID` property in multiple places. Both in the `SELECT` statement, then in both the `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements as well. You cannot reuse properties in the way I have done it because the `?`s are filled in with the properties from the dataframe in order and I cannot find a way to reuse the properties.

From my understanding, my last ditch effort should be using a `for` loop to iterate through the dataframe and do single executes on each row. In my mind, that's the only way I can assign some variables to then use to build my SQL query, however, I'd love to know if there's an easier or better way to go about this.

Comment: Please be very careful with `MERGE`, at the very least you absolutely need `HOLDLOCK` on the target table to avoid race conditions. See [this post](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/) for a bunch of other potential issues.

Comment: @AaronBertrand thank you for the suggestion! I didn't realize what I was getting myself in to. I really appreciate the guidance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  You can assign the parameters to local variables and reuse them:

```
declare @myId int = ?;
declare @myName nvarchar(200) = ?;
declare @myProperty float = ?;
declare @myOtherProperty datetime2(7) = ?;

MERGE myTable as target
USING (
  SELECT myID from myTable
  WHERE myID = @myId
) AS source (myID) ON (target.myID = source.myID)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (myID, myName, myProperty, myOtherProperty)
VALUES(@myId, @myName, @myProperty, @myOtherProperty)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET myName=@myName, myProperty=@myProperty, etc...;
```

The key enabler here is that you are sending a TSQL batch to SQL Server.  It doesn't have to be a single statement.

If you want to send lots of data to SQL Server, though, you can also just send a JSON document using a single NVarchar(max) parameter, and parse it into a table using [OPENJSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) on the server.  That would enable you to send a whole table of data to SQL Server to use in the MERGE.